# HTML: How to split list (of <tr>-s) into multiple chunks with keeping the header?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list that is too long, and it is needed to fit without scrolling, but I can't figure out how to split this into 2 or 3 or 4 chunks. I copied a list below, the real list is having 200 or more rows of data. Let's say I'd like to have chunks with no more than 3 rows inside.
Is it possible to make more than one chunk of this and keeping the header too?
(The data comes from an SQL selection and constantly changing).

```
<div id="FIller1" class="dbtable">  
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td class="b3">Filled ID1</td>
                <td class="n3">Filled ID2</td>
                <td class="n3">Filled ID3</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
                
        <tbody>
            
                
            
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>110</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>110-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>AAA</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>111</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>111-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>BBB</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>112</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>112-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>CCC</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>113</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>113-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>DDD</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>114</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>114-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>EEE</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>115</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>115-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>FFF</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="index"><span>116</span></td>
                <td class="n2"><span>116-2</span></td>
                <td class="b2"><span>GGG</span></td>
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>    
        </div>
```

Comment: Add more `<td>` to your `<tr>`

Comment: I dont understand how could this help me, sorry.

Comment: Or do you ask if you can add more `<tbody>`? Yes you can

Comment: No, im not asking that if i can add more td or tbody or tdivs. Im asking if there is a way to split overflowing list into 3 chunks. i have 200 rows of auto filled data from db. Its working with 6 columns with 6 runs of sql select and with delete rows, but its comlicated, and buggy, but i cant figure out something that works and is simple :D

Comment: So please describe `chunk` - how you want it to be?

Comment: Maybe split the one big table into 2 or 4 tables? for-loop the data every 100 or 50 rows.